# Login Process Taking Forever (10 Minutes)

Tags: windows, networking, performance, login

My work computer connected through LAN is taking forever to login. It takes 10 minutes to login to the computer.

How can I debug this issue?

UPDATE:

Turns out it was some services that were running in the background that was causing this problem.

Comment: for the beginning - what OS are you using? what distro?

Comment: Using Windows XP! distro??

Comment: Is it still slow booting in Safe Mode? Safe Mode with Network Support ?

Comment: Care to tell us what services you found that were causing problems?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It was the scanning services by the cooperate! Like virus scan and stuff!

Answer (score 1):

> Many of the slow login issues caused by using an
>   Internet domain name as your internal domain and not having the right DNS
>   server specified on the client trying to authenticate in the domain.

[(source)](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-191381_36_0.html)

Comment: @azamsharp: If this doesn't solve the problem, then it would help to have some details about your network architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing the user's profile.